# How do I change a variable value in Xilinx SDK debugger using Linux TCF Agent connected to our target?

Tags: linux, debugging, sdk, xilinx

I am connected to our target over ethernet using the Linux TCF agent to debug an application.

I've used a lot of debuggers over my 25 year career, but this is my first time using Eclipse/Linux/Xilinx environment.  I can set break points.  I can single step through the code.  I can view variables.  I can view memory.  I can type a new value in the memory location, but the variable value doesn't change.  I tried to click or double click the value in the Variables pane.  I tried right clicking to see if it would give me an option to modify the value.

I'm not sure what good a debugging tool is if I can't change a variable value to alter the execution path of my software...

Comment: I think that sometimes the variable view is out of sync with the actual values. One thing you can try is to annotate the address of the variable, then change it from the memory view. Does this help?

Comment: So far, that is the only way that I have been able to change a variable value.  It is a variable of type bool, so I had to get the right portion of the 32-bit value changed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the hacky solution we came up in the comments, which is to get the address of a variable and then modify them through the `mr` command from the `xsct console`, the same console provide commands to properly g[et/set a local variable](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1400-vitis-embedded/locals).

The syntax is the following:

```
locals [options] [variable-name [variable-value]]
```

And an example:

```
locals my_int_var 10
locals my_float_var 1.4
```